# Is it possible to solve the XOR problem by two hidden layer with linear activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is it possible to solve the XOR problem by two hidden layers with linear activation functions?

```
X1 X2  Y
 1  1  0
 1  0  1
 0  1  1
 0  0  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A network with two hidden layers with linear activation functions is still a generalized linear model (GLM) in the from of $y=f(w_2(w_1x+b_1)+b_2)$. So it is only able to learn a linear decision boundary.